Retrieve Line Number Information in Thrown Exception - Power Platform Dataverse Plugin Package
Is it possible to retrieve line numbers corresponding to source code when throwing an exception for a Power Platform Plugin Package?
Background

Plugin Packages are built as nuget packages and registered on against the Power Platform
Packages are locked into .NET version net462 as an SDK style project
Normally when throwing an exception, the stack trace is present, but line numbers are not
In this process I'm building in debug mode

Code

When using the following code: (link to github with full project below in the Links section)

            try
            {
                logic.ThrowException();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var stackTrace = new StackTrace(ex, true);
                var linenumber = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetFileLineNumber();
                var file = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
                var method = stackTrace.GetFrame(0).GetMethod();
                localPluginContext.Trace($@"
                    {nameof(linenumber)}: {linenumber}, 
                    {nameof(file)}: {file}, 
                    {nameof(stackTrace)}: {stackTrace}");
            }



I get the following trace output:

[+923ms] - [Execute] - Entered PluginStackTraceTest.StackTraceTestPlugin.Execute() Correlation Id: f12333aa-1894-4aa2-b5d5-f600e146e0ea, Initiating User: 1b4822ba-b1c5-eb11-8235-0022480a9839
[+0ms] - [ExecuteDataversePlugin] - Test 7
[+0ms] - [ExecuteDataversePlugin] - 
                    linenumber: 0, 
                    file: , 
                    stackTrace:    at PluginStackTraceTest.Logic.StackTraceTestLogic.ThrowException()
   at PluginStackTraceTest.StackTraceTestPlugin.ExecuteDataversePlugin(ILocalPluginContext localPluginContext)

[+0ms] - [Execute] - Exiting PluginStackTraceTest.StackTraceTestPlugin.Execute()

What I've Tried

I've added a Directory.Build.props file as specified in this SO Post: Include pdb files into my nuget (nupkg) files
I've also set the properties in the .csproj file

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Based on https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/producing-packages-with-source-link/ -->
    <!-- Publish the repository URL in the built .nupkg (in the NuSpec <Repository> element) -->
    <PublishRepositoryUrl>true</PublishRepositoryUrl>

    <!-- Embed source files that are not tracked by the source control manager in the PDB -->
    <EmbedUntrackedSources>true</EmbedUntrackedSources>
    <EmbedSources>True</EmbedSources>

    <!-- Embed symbols containing Source Link in the main file (exe/dll) -->
    <DebugType>embedded</DebugType>
    
    <ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>False</ExcludeGeneratedDebugSymbol>
  </PropertyGroup>



I've inspected the nuget package with dotpeek and confirmed that the pdb metadata is present in the package

I'm assuming the metadata has been merged with the dll because when I unzip the package I see:

I've also tried adding the parameter: <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols> to the PropertyGroup, but then that just makes a separate symbols file:


Any suggestions / recommendations would be greatly appreciated and thanks in advance.
Links
cli-create-package
github repo - PluginStackTraceTest
